# DbContextOptionsBuilder does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlite'

Tags: asp.net, dbcontext

Dotnet Core Web API throws when trying to use SQLite for my application

DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlite' and no accessible extension method 'UseSqlite'

how to fix this?

I have tried using.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding SQLite package.

On your startup file use this

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

On your project file use this

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.1"/>
```

then you are ready to use SQLite

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => 
    x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: `<PackageReference ...>` should be placed in an `<ItemGroup>...` like so: `<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Answer (score 9):

If you get this error you might have forgotten to install the *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite* package

In Visual Studio go to **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console** and type:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

Or if you're using .NET CLI type this in your shell:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

This command will also add the corresponding `<PackageReference ..>` tag to the project file as mentioned by RedWan.